# JS: Class getters/setters vs. just changing property directly

Tags: javascript

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name.toUpperCase();
  }

  set name(newName) {
    this._name = newName; 
  }
}

let newPerson  = new Person("mike")
```

What is the benefit of a getter and setter?  Can't I still get it via `newPerson._name` and get `mike`?  And to set it, can't I just do `newPerson._name = "Phil"` to set it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the getter should provide you with a hint:

```
  get name() {
    return this._name.toUpperCase();
  }
```

It can allow you to perform possibly-complicated logic, disguised as a plain property lookup. For another example, consider if you had `firstName` and `lastName` properties instead - then, you can make `name` a getter/setter for the actual underlying properties:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    // Invoke the setter below
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._firstName + ' ' + this._lastName;
  }

  set name(newName) {
    const [first, last] = newName.split(' ');
    this._firstName = first;
    this._lastName = last;
  }
}

let newPerson  = new Person("John Smith") 
console.log(newPerson.name);
```

This sort of functionality (running logic and returning something custom instead of returning just the plain property value) would be impossible without getters/setters.

That said, for your original code, except for the `toUpperCase` part, yeah, the getter/setter isn't really doing much for you.

> can't I just do newPerson._name = "Phil" to set it ?

Yes, you can. Underscores are generally used to indicate that a property *shouldn't* be used external to a class, but they don't *forbid* it entirely. If you want to make a property truly private, use `#` private field syntax.

```js
class Person {
  #firstName;
  #lastName;
  constructor(name) {
    // Invoke the setter below
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.#firstName + ' ' + this.#lastName;
  }

  set name(newName) {
    const [first, last] = newName.split(' ');
    this.#firstName = first;
    this.#lastName = last;
  }
}

let newPerson  = new Person("John Smith") 
console.log(newPerson.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few benefits to encapsulation, including validating data (throwing an error if you set the wrong value) and formatting it appropriately (returning "User has no name" instead of `undefined`). It also means that if you decide to change how the object's data is handled, you can point a getter/setter to new data without having to update an outdated property constantly. If you prefer the syntax of properties, JavaScript has the [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object to implement these getter/setter features.

This [article](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/%7Ejsa/UMLJavaShortCourse09/CGOutput/Unit3/unit3(0809)/page_13.htm) on encapsulation might be of use.